# Simpler formula for a 5 nested if command

Tags: excel-formula

I have been scouring forums for a solution but am striking out so far.  I want to do a countA of all non empty cells -1.  The data I'm pulling from is in Q:U, and I want to do a count based on the header of the columns in row 2.  Because of where the data comes from in Q:U, the column order is not always going to be the same.

I have the following string which works where I can replace each instance of "Test" with the particular header I am looking for.  Is there a simpler command using a combination if Index and Match that would work?  Or even a better solution?

```
=IF($Q$2="Test",COUNTIF($Q$3:$Q$150,">0")-1,IF($R$2="Test",COUNTIF($R$3:$R$150,">0")-1,IF($S$2="Test",COUNTIF($S$3:$S$150,">0")-1,IF($T$2="Test",COUNTIF($T$3:$T$150,">0")-1,IF($U$2="Test",COUNTIF($U$3:$U$150,">0")-1,0)))))
```

Comment: Please include sample data and your desired results as well (Your description and attempt appears to be good). You can use a site [like this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) for converting your excel sample data to something that will paste here nicely (adding four spaces to the beginning of each line to have it format properly, or highlight the block after pasting it and hit the code format button at the top).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I will add data/results in the future.  @Scott Craner just gave the perfect answer to my query before I could add data/results.

Comment: @ScottCraner is pretty awesome like that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($Q$3:$U$150,0,MATCH("Test",$Q$2:$U$2,0)),">0")-1
```

You can replace `"Test"` with a cell reference that you then can change to look up different columns by their name.